# Creating a function to loop through Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a function to loop through json file and based upon specific condition met want to add the value of the json keys to array but not able to accomplish the same.

Following is the json:

```
$a1 = [    {
        "name": "sachin",
        "surname": "",
    },
    {
        "name": "Rajesh",
        "surname": "Mehta"

    }
]
```

and the function that i have created is below:

```
function addingkeyval
{
param ($key,
        [Array]$tobeaddedarr)

$a1 | Select-Object -Property name,surname | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.$key-eq "")
    {
    }
    else
    {     
    $tobeaddedarr +=$_.$key+","
    }
}

}
```

when i cal this  function with the statement:

```
$surnamearr = @()
addingkeyval -key surname -tobeaddedarr $surnamearr

i want the output in the array $surnamearr as below
("Mehta")
```

somehow i am not able to add the value in the array can anyone help me in achieving the same

Comment: Thanks for accepting - note that I've just tweaked the answer slightly, so that (hypothetical) input objects without a `.surname` property are filtered out as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
$surnamearr = ([string[]] (ConvertFrom-Json $a1).surname) -ne ''
```

- `ConvertFrom-Json $a1` converts the JSON array to an array of PowerShell custom objects (type `[pscustomobject]`).
- `(...).surname` extracts the values of all `.surname` properties of the objects in the resulting array, using [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).
- Cast `[string[]]` ensures that the result is treated as an array (it wouldn't be, if the array in `$a1` happened to contain just *one* element) and explicitly casts to *strings*, so that filtering nonempty values via `-ne ''` also works for input objects that happen to have no `.surname` property.
- `-ne ''` filters out all empty-string elements from the resulting array (with an array as the LHS, comparison operators such as `-ne` act as *array filters* rather than returning a Boolean value).

The result is that `$surnamearr` is an array containing all non-empty `.surname` property values.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$tobeaddedarr +=$_.$key+","`

This statement implicitly creates a *new* array, distinct from the array reference the caller passed via the `$tobeaddedarr` parameter variable - therefore, the caller never sees the change.

You generally cannot pass an array to be *appended to* in-place, because arrays are *immutable* with respect to their number of elements.

While you *could* pass an *mutable* array-like structure (such as `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]` instance, which you can append to with its `.Add()` method), it is much simpler to build a new array inside the function and *output it*.

Therefore, you could write your function as:

```sh
function get-keyval
{
  param ($key)

  # Implicitly output the elements of the array output by using this command.
  ([string[]] (ConvertFrom-Json $key).surname) -ne ''
}

$surnamearr = get-keyval surname
```

Note:

- Outputting an array or a collection in PowerShell by default *enumerates* it: it sends its elements *one by one* to the output stream (pipeline).

  - While it is possible to output an array *as a whole*, via the unary form of `,`, the array-construction operator (
    `, (([string[]] (ConvertFrom-Json $a1).surname) -ne '')`), which improves performance, the problem is that the caller may not expect this behavior, especially not in a *pipeline*.
- If you capture the output in a variable, such as `$surnamearr` here, PowerShell automatically collects the individual output objects in an `[object[]]` array for you; note, however, that a *single* output object is returned as-is, i.e. *not* wrapped in an array.

  - You can wrap `@(...)` around the function call to ensure that you *always* get an array
  - Alternatively, type-constrain the receiving variable: `[array] $surnamearr = ...`, which also creates an `[object[]]` array, or something like `[string[]] $surnamearr = ...`, which creates a strongly typed string array.